# Android Image Loading Speeds

Tags: android, performance, image, load, format

Does anyone out there know what image format results in the fastest loading speeds?
I haven't done any checks, but if someone has, please comment.

I know that the android docs say that it supports: `.JPG`, `.GIF`, `.PNG`, `.BMP`, `.WEBP`.
Lets say that I have to load many images very quickly, which format should I use to get the best performance? I am already using low-res and hi-res images. Loading the low-res images is very fast, but if you scroll my screen very fast, sometimes it can't quite keep up (there is a black section).

Also, does the method of loading matter? I'm currently using `BitmapFactory.DecodeFile(path)` as it is the easiest. I load the images asynchronously, so there is no 'hiccup' in the UI but we sometimes see black sections for a few milliseconds.

I know this also has to do with I/O speeds, but lets live in an ideal world where this speed is negligible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is, the bottleneck will be I/O speed, not CPU speed. Which means the most compressed format will be the fastest, even though it takes CPU time to decompress. So the answer is JPEG.

Answer (score 1):

My two cents: I've done some tests, with a large image (1200x1700) loaded as a background resource (and resized to fit the fragment width) in a Fragment onCreateView() method.

Here's 4 timing measurements (image loading + layout inflate) for each image format in ms:

```
PNG: 212 200 188 220 (saved with Photoshop)
PNG: 200 196 224 192 (compressed with TinyPNG)
JPG: 248 248 260 244
```

So I guess PNG (no matter which, Photoshop or TinyPNG) is slightly faster to load than JPG.

Comment: Data. I like answers with data instead of guesses, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Surprisingly the IO is not the bottleneck.

1024x1024x32BPP image.

From the native side, I have more flexibility on what I'm loading.

PNG : 109ms
Custom TGA loader : 39ms
Custom RAW loader : 32ms

The profiler shows PNG loader spent an age decompressing, dwarfing file IO.